# case insensitive access of node property in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

in neo4j 3.5, I can access some specific node like so:

```
match (b:SomeLabel) where b.MyFirstValue = 1 return b.Name
```

However, I would also like to access the property like so:

```
match (b:SomeLabel) where b.myfirstvalue = 1 return b.Name
```

Is there a way to achieve this in cypher, short of re-inserting all the data after ensuring all the property names are cased properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to rename a specific property, you can use the [apoc.refactor.rename.nodeProperty](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#rename-label-type-property) procedure.

For example, this query:

```
CALL apoc.refactor.rename.nodeProperty('myfirstvalue', 'MyFirstValue')
```

will make the specified property name change across all nodes. Or you can limit the change by specifying a list of nodes as the third argument.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. I am actually trying to see if I can access the many node and relation properties that are already stored in the database without worrying if I have the case right. I didn't find a corresponding apoc procedure for that.

Comment: There is no APOC procedure for such a specialized use case. Also, how would you determine what "canonic" name to use for the many forms of the same name?